# Why doesn't my new .c source build after adding to Eclipse 4.17.0 on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, eclipse-cdt

1. added test3.c to my Eclipse hello world project.
2. added function void test3(void){} to it.
3. added extern void test3(void);  to my hello_world.c
4. added test3(); to my hello_world.c [image]ie. void main(void){ test3(); }

But when I build all, I get:
c:/gnu-gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:\SDK\AmbiqSuite_R3.1.1\boards\apollo3_evb\examples\hello_world\gcc/../src/hello_world.c:21: undefined reference to `test3'

Comment: Your project configuration is significant here, and you have not conveyed any relevant details of that.  However, I *speculate* that your `test3.c` may not be included in the build because it is not in the `src/` directory (where `hello_world.c` is), but is instead one level up.